# MySql query taking too long - django on webfaction

Tags: mysql, django

I use django on webfaction, and I've got a "MySql query taking too long" message, 
the sql is

```
SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `main_userprofile` WHERE `main_userprofile`.`id` = 98
```

This is a rather simple sql, why the query taken too long?

here it is the 'create table':

```
main_userprofile | CREATE TABLE `main_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sex` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `active_number` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `work_number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
...
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1652 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

the id is the primary key

the explain:

```
explain SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `main_userprofile` WHERE `main_userprofile`.`id` = 98;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main_userprofile | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: what does EXPLAIN PLAN tell you when you run the query?

Comment: try to check the table with mysqlcheck

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `id` is not indexed, isn't it. Is `id` the primary key of your table? Could you post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE main_userprofile;`?

Comment: thank you, here it is:
<pre>
main_userprofile | CREATE TABLE `main_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sex` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `active_number` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `work_number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
...
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1652 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 | 
</pre>
the id is the primary key